# VBA Excel "Object Required" error

Tags: vba, excel

My codes gives me a Object Required 424 error on this line:

```
lngRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

My full code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
'    If Target.Column > 2 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox "You must only fill in one of the two columns"
            Target.ClearContents
            GoTo ExitSub
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Column = 7 Then
        If Target.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox "You must only fill in one of the two columns"
            Target.ClearContents
            GoTo ExitSub
        End If
    End If

    Dim arrData() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim myNum As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    myNum = Target.Value

    If Target.Column = 6 Then
    With BogieInspectionPoints 'this is a sheet name
        lngRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arrData = .Range("a1:b" & lngRow)
    End With
    End If

    If Target.Column = 7 Then
    With WagonInspectionPoints 'this is a sheet name
        lngRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arrData = .Range("a1:b" & lngRow)
    End With
    End If

    For i = 1 To lngRow
        If myNum = arrData(i, 1) Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value = arrData(i, 2)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: what is the `BogieInspectionPoints` ? Is it sheet name or vba sheet object?

Comment: What are BogieInspectionPoints or WagonInspectionPoints?

Comment: Those are indeed sheet names!

Comment: in that case use `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BogieInspectionPoints")`

Comment: Where is the line of code that sets the `BogieInspectionPoints` object value? Can you post it? It could be out of scope.

Comment: Now I get "Type mismatch" on this line: `arrData = .Range("a2:b" & lngRow)`

Comment: @Bmo , this is all I have...

Comment: Well, put a breakpoint on the line and tell us what it says in the locals window for `BogieInspectionpoints` and `lngRow`

Comment: With BogieInspectionPoints 'this is a sheet name 'no its not (not declared as dim in the sub) , so no object, thus the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like those sheet variables aren't set.

You will need to add this at the top.

```
Dim BogieInspectionPoints as Worksheet
Dim WagonInspectionPoints as Worksheet

Set BogieInspectionPoints = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BogieInspectionPoints")
Set WagonInspectionPoints = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WagonInspectionPoints")
```

I was assuming there was other code. When you add this line all the `With` statements *should* process correctly using the code you posted.

What you're doing with the `With` statements is shorthanding the object. Instead of writing

```
BogieInspectionPoints.Range("A1")
```

'More code

You can write

```
With BogieInspectionPoints
 .Range("A1")
End With
```

It keeps you from having to write the full object name out.

Comment: How can I let Excel remove the text in column 8, when I remove the number in column 6 or 7?